# C# Running Casted Method Instead of Actual Method

Tags: c#, class, methods, overriding

I have types of ViewComponents that extend a single ViewComponent class. In my View I have it looping over ViewComponents and printing them. Unfortunately it's pulling the casted methods instead of the actual class methods. Ex:

```
using System;

namespace test
{
  class Component {
    public string getType() {
      return "Component";
    }
  }

  class ButtonComponent: Component {
    public string getType() {
      return "Button";
    }
  }

  public class test
  {
    public static void Main() {
      Component[] components = new Component[1];
      components [0] = new ButtonComponent();

      Console.WriteLine(components[0].getType()); // prints Component
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the button to print "Button" instead of "Component"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining two separate instance methods, `Component.getType()` and `ButtonComponent.getType()`. You most likely got a compiler warning about this as well, something to the effect of "Method `ButtonComponent.getType()` hides method from base class. Use the `new` keyword if this is intended." This warning is letting you know about the behavior you are experiencing, and there's a [page about it in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx) too.

What you want to do instead is declare a `virtual` method on the base class and `override` it in the subclass:

```
class Component {
    public virtual string getType() {
      return "Component";
    }
}

class ButtonComponent: Component {
    public override string getType() {
      return "Button";
    }
}
```

This way the implementation of `ButtonComponent.getType()` *replaces* that of the base type.

---

Side note: In general the accepted convention for method names is PascalCase (not camelCase). Consider renaming your method `GetType()` with a capital G.

Answer (score 1):

Use virtual and override keywords:

```
class Component {
    public virtual string getType() {
       return "Component";
    }
}

class ButtonComponent: Component {
    public override string getType() {
        return "Button";
    }
}
```

:)